# Crash when typing

Tags: ios, wkwebview

Whernever I summon the keyboard and type anything, it crashes

> -[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102bf4af0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull
>   _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102bf4af0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029cfe65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00000001037ffdeb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001029d848d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010292590a
>   ___forwarding_** + 970    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029254b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001029bbf23 -[NSTaggedPointerString
>   compare:options:range:locale:] + 243  6   Foundation
>   0x0000000102d62e37 -[NSString compare:options:range:] + 29    7   UIKit 
>   0x0000000100ef6e6f -[UIPhysicalKeyboardEvent _matchesKeyCommand:] +
>   303   8   UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b3fd
>   -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 364  9   UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
>     10  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2
>   -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801  11  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
>     12  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2
>   -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801  13  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
>     14  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2
>   -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801  15  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
>     16  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2
>   -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801  17  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
>     18  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2
>   -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801  19  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
>     20  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2
>   -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801  21  UIKit                               0x0000000100e1b5b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
>     22  UIKit                               0x0000000100c2d1aa
>   -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 397     23  UIKit                               0x0000000100c06838 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5469    24 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001028fba31
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001028f195c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001028f0e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867     27  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001028f0828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     28  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000105a89ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  29  UIKit
>   0x0000000100c0c610 UIApplicationMain + 171    30  TMEF
>   0x00000001007a2b6d main + 109     31  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010434192d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Any suggestions?

Comment: on what device or in what simulator AND can you please provide a minimal example app that shows this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here: [What is causing NSNull length unrecognized selector keyCommand error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633242/what-is-causing-nsnull-length-unrecognized-selector-keycommand-error#comment44971094_26633242)

Basically somewhere in your navigation stack there is a storyboard that has these lines

```
  <keyCommands>
          <keyCommand/>
  </keyCommands>
```

Open your storyboard in text editor and search for that. Note that it may be not in the storyboard/scene that is causing crash, but in any scene used in navigation stack.